# Maximum rows in a Matrix field

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

Is there a theoretical (or practical) limit to the number of rows you can have in a Matrix field?

Let's say each row has 5 single line text fields and a date field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say with that kind of data, the practical limit would be pretty high, since each row would have very little data (compared to, say, a Playa field in one or more columns).

Said practical limit would be based on a combination of your server memory (for selecting and iterating all the row data, then all the regex used in parsing each row in your template), and browser memory (due to the required javascript in the CP).

Looking at the Matrix fieldtype:

- any given Matrix field will only display up to 1000 rows on the Publish screen
- the default limit for Matrix rows in templates is 100 (though you could set this to something higher in the template tag)

Comment: Thank you Derek. I'm thinking that for this project this could be a good way to build what's needed.